# SQL Server FORMAT() Function Parameter Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have some SQL code:

```
format(overseas * 1.00 / total_sales, 'p')
```

What does 'p' mean?

Comment: This is where you read the reference docs...

Comment: I can't fathom would deem this question worthy of an upvote. The documentation clearly shows what this means and the OP didn't appear to even attempt to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'p' stands for percent.

> **["P" or "p"     Percent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**
>
> Result: Number multiplied by 100 and displayed with a percent symbol.
>
> 1 ("P", en-US) -> 100.00 %